# How to open the file under cursor in vim when its listing directory contents(Netrw Directory Listing)

Tags: vim

I can press o but it creates a new window and opens the file there. I want it to open in the same window. At least it should display on the same window each time open some file but it creates new windows for each file I open. Also is there a way to make it open as a vertical split and not horizontal split?
Where can I find the complete documentation/cheatsheet of all possible commands in 'Netrw Directory Listing' mode?

Comment: Remark, `s:NetrwGetWord()` function gets the filename under the cursor, but need a hack to call the s: functions https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17866/are-script-local-functions-sfuncname-unit-testable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answers to your other questions, see

```
:help netrw
```

for all the documentation,

```
:help netrw-v
```

for using a vertically-split window, and

```
:help netrw-browse-maps
```

for a listing of the normal-mode commands (maps).

Answer (score 5):

Here is quick reference from Help

```
  ---           -----------------
  Map           Quick Explanation
  ---           -----------------
 <cr>   Netrw will enter the directory or read the file 
 <del>  Netrw will attempt to remove the file/directory                                                                
   D    Attempt to remove the file(s)/directory(ies)                            
   o    Enter the file/directory under the cursor in a new   
    browser window.  A horizontal split is used.
   O    Obtain a file specified by cursor                    
   p    Preview the file                                     
   P    Browse in the previously used window                            
   qf   Display information on file                                                         
   R    Rename the designed file(s)/directory(ies)            
   t    Enter the file/directory under the cursor in a new tab           
   v    Enter the file/directory under the cursor in a new   
    browser window.  A vertical split is used.
   x    View file with an associated program                 
   %    Open a new file in netrw's current directory
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Netwr listing press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.